# Fastest way to display 5000 post titles?

Tags: sql

I want to display all CPT titles on its archive.
I don't want to use pagination. All must be in 1 page.
There are 5000 posts.
Echoing the_title on the archive loop works but it's slow.
What's the fastest way to display this? Maybe using SQL wpdb->get_results?

Comment: This will depend on a few things, I'm assuming you want these to be clickable links not just words? You'll also want caching so that it only does it the once. There's also the problem that it might be 5000 now, but requirements could change in a year and it could be upped to 15k. Otherwise, 5 thousand titles is a lot of text to read, this page will have more content than some short novels, is it really such a good idea? Perhaps some more context would be helpful

Comment: They Will be clickable. The idea is have an index. All in one place. So people don't have to waste time with 500 pages and use Ctrl+F ti find things fast.

Comment: @MichaelRogers If you use `get_posts()` to retrieve the posts, you can loop through the array of posts and simply use `echo $post->post_title;` to output the title. It's probably the filters that are used by `the_title();` that slow the process. Also the `global $post` variable can be accessed within a while loop.

Comment: Would it not make sense then to have a search box instead and use `search.php`? Or an Autocomplete

Comment: There's a searchbox. But wp search is pretty terrible. 1 off character and no results. Not to mention expensive. Auto complete would kill MySQL on a busy site. We would need a SAS solution like algolia but that cost a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion and from what i've seen on testing. Using any WordPress function will slow things down dramatically. The fastest way i found to do this is by querying MySQL directly and grabbing only the things needed.

For example:

```
$products = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_title, post_name FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_type = 'products'", ARRAY_A );

    echo '<ol>';        

        foreach ($products as $product) {               

        echo '<li><a href="https://domain.com/products/'.$product['post_name'].'/">'.$product['post_title'].'</a></li>';

        }        

    echo '</ol>';
```

It does it in a few ms (200~) with 1600 posts vs several seconds (3~) using WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is (If you must use a WordPress loop) to implement Object cache to cache the query. This will make the expensive query run only once, so the next time the page is requested the page will be generated much faster.